# Permutations and terminology

Tags: permutations, terminology, permutation-cycles

Say I have the following permutation

$$\sigma ={\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\1&2&3&8&4&5&6&7\end{pmatrix}}$$

which consists to let unchanged some first elements from $1$ to $k$ and to apply a circular shift on the elements $\{k+1, \ldots, n\}$.

What is the name for such transformation?

Thank you

Comment: The name is "a *$5$-cycle* in $S_8$", namely $\sigma=(48765)$.

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde Does this (n-k)-cycle let unchanged the first $k$ elements?

Comment: Yes, it keeps $1$,$2$, $3$ fixed (unchanged). Have a look at the cycle notation for permutations.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks again. Why do you have written $\sigma=(48765)$? Is the order correct?

Comment: Have a look at the cycle notation: $(45)$ means that $4$ goes to $5$ and $5$ goes to $4$. Then $(48765)$ means that $4\mapsto 8\mapsto 7\mapsto 6\mapsto 5\mapsto 4\mapsto\cdots $

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah ok thank you. I am wondering if I have well written my permutation, because what I have in mind is to apply a right shift to the sequence $\{4, 5, 6, 7,8\}$. This notion of cycle seems different, does'n it?

Comment: You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1, 2, 3$ each map to themselves. $1\to 1$. Period.  $2\to 2.$ Period.  $3\to 3.$ Period.  We can represent this as $(1)(2)(3)$, but typically this is not customary.

So we can start with $4$:

$4 \to 8$, then

$8 \to 7$, then

$7\to 6$,

then $6\to 5$, and finally,

$5 \to 4$, completing the five cycle (bringing us back to the starting number for the cycle, $4$:

That gives us the permutation $\sigma = (48765)$.  This can also be written as $$\sigma = (1)(2)(3)(48765) = (48765)$$

---

To get the cycle you are looking for, you'll need the following permutation:

$\alpha ={\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\1&2&3&5&6&7&8&4\end{pmatrix}} = (45678)$

The name for this transformation is merely "permutation" $\alpha$ on the set $S$ of $8$ numbers, specifically, both $\alpha, \sigma \in \mathbb S_8$, the group of permutations on $S$.

If we were talking about vertices of an octagon, numbered 1-8, then $(12345678)$ could be described as a rotation of the octagon.

Comment: Thanks @amWhy As I have written to Dietrich, I think I am reffering to another kind of cycle.

Comment: Top number goes to bottom number in each column.

Comment: Thank you. So writing left shift is straightforward, but for writing a right shift we need to read from top to bottom?

Comment: Yes, the numbers in the top row represent the 8 possible numbers to permute.  Where each of those numbers goes is written immediately below the number, in the second row.

Comment: Thanks again. So, if I have a sequence of 8 unknown numbers, but I know that when I will have these numbers, I will right shift the 5 last numbers. How can I write this function, terminologically?

Comment: There is no problem for the left shift. It is the right shift which is embarrassing because I need to write the outputs, and this is impossible for very long sequences

Comment: I just take the inverse. Ok thank you !